# Cloudinary upload image widget does not work as expected

Tags: cloudinary

I am using the upload image widget without success.

1) `result.info.path` returns invalid url.
2) There is no preview of the uploaded images due to no.1
3) No images are were uploaded to my media folder at Cloudinary.

**Fiddle**:
https://jsfiddle.net/7uqb83t1/

These are my **preset** settings:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Can someone share a working version of this widget + preset settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On successful upload, you need to check `result.info.secure_url` for a link to the asset. Currently, in your preset, you're using Async which means the incoming transformation is performed in the background (asynchronously), and as such, you will get a `pending` result. Async assumes you're using a Notification URL as a webhook where you'll receive the Upload API response when the processing is complete. In your case, I'd recommend turning the Async off.

Also, your incoming transformation configured in the preset is not valid and because of that, you will be getting an `error` on upload. Please console.log this in your JSFiddle to see it. Essentially, it'll be -

> Auto gravity can only be used with crop, fill, lfill, fill_pad or
>   thumb

'auto' gravity (`g_auto`) implies cropping (automatically selecting the most interesting part of the image to focus on) and therefore you need to use an appropriate crop mode. 'scale' keeps all image data and no cropping is made so that is why `g_auto` can't work with it. Please see the following section of the documentation for details on the different crop modes - https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformation_reference#crop_parameter - which will help you decide which one you want to use.

Lastly, you should also consider updating your incoming transformation so that it only resizes once, since currently, resizing it three times with the same crop mode is redundant. For example, you can use `c_scale,q_auto,w_687` only, or if you want with 'auto' gravity you can try `c_fill,g_auto,q_auto,w_687`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
I modified the preset as you suggested and it works except a small issue.
After the upload the `Done` button is disabled you can see it in the fiddle, can see why?

Also,
I don't see an option for the user to delete/update images that were uploaded, is there something out of the box or I should do it by myself?

Comment: @OffirPe'er - Apart from when in progress, the `Done` button is disabled when the Widget is opened `inline`. You can either close the Widget automatically upon successful upload `myWidget.close();` or show it as a modal and the user can click `Done` or `X` to close.

Comment: Thx,
Is there an option to delete an image that was uploaded?
Maybe using a `X` button on the thumbnails?

In case a user uploaded an image and later regreted.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to delete the image from the client-side solely. However, that is available only up to 10 minutes after the image has been uploaded.

To use it you need to enable "Return delete token" from the Upload Preset configuration. Then, since you are using the 'thumbnails' upon upload, you will see an `X` button next to the thumbnail that clicking on it would trigger the delete.

You can also extract the token from `result.info.delete_token` and send a request to Cloudinary to delete it.
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#deleting_client_side_uploaded_images

Comment: I got the return delete token by setting it in the preset under upload control, now that I have my delete token how can I use it using the upload widget, I couldn't find a word about it..

Comment: When you upload an image successfully you will see the thumbnail below the Widget based on your JSFiddle. Next to it, you will see an `X` button that will use that `delete_token` internally to delete it.

Comment: The `X` was so small I couldn't see him, thank you for telling me this!

Comment: Btw, they say in the docs I put my facebook id, but it seems like the widget uses Cloudinary facebook id, did you notice that?

Comment: The `facebookAppId` is optional, and if not provided, will use the default Cloudinary Facebook app - https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget#facebook_source. If you have a dedicated one you should use that one.

Comment: Is there a way to control the iframe height? On my laptop I can't see the top bar where the sources, I couldn't find anything about this.

Comment: For reference, if anyone follows this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61371762/cloudinary-iframe-close-button-sources-bar-is-hidden-because-iframe-content