# Cloudinary - Iframe close button + sources bar is hidden because Iframe content is too high

Tags: cloudinary

As you can see from the image, the iframe content is too big and it hides the `X` button + `Sources` bar.
Is there any option to make it's content a bit smaller?
[image]

This css seems to be the problem:

```
  @@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
            #uw-glamor-396 .css-5anb0a, #uw-glamor-396 [data-css-5anb0a] {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                width: 767px;
                height: 610px;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
        }
```

If the height would be 450px instead of 610px it would fix the issue.

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d1kLowrg/) raises the issue, open it with your laptop and expand a little bit the result window to get the `Drag and Drop` box.

This is how it looks like without the bookmark tab in my laptop with 100%, I use Chrome:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it isnt possible to change this currently. Its a known issue but up until now there havent been any complaints that i know of. Typically apps that host the widget are in desktop resolutions so there's enough vertical space or its in mobile res and then the widget switches to the mobile layout.

Ill look into promoting this issue internally.
In the meantime, can you share some details about your app, how does it display the widget? What makes it not have enough vertical space?

Comment: this fiddle looks different than your screenshot . its using the inlineContainer parameter. When you inline the widget, the close button isnt shown by design. The issue you reported in your original question relates to limited vertical space for the widget. Is that a scenario you face outside of something like jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi, 
Sorry, wrong fiddle, I edited the question with the correct one.

Comment: Of course,
I raised this issue because I can't see the `X` button and the sources bar when I use it in my website with my laptop, only when I zoom out to 80% it appears.
They just need to minimize a little bit the `Drag and Drop` place holder, it's too big.